# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: mysql

I am not sure why this isn't working. Here is the code it is referencing.

```
function db_connection($query) {
    mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'runner_db_user', 'runner_db_password')
        OR die(fail('Could not connect to database.'));
    mysql_select_db('ntc_race_info');

    return mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your installation of `PHP` has been compiled with `mysql` support. Run a `phpinfo()` to see if the `php_mysql` extension module is loaded. Create a test web page containing

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

then run it,If you don't see page for MySQL, you need to recompile `PHP` with MySQL support, or reinstall a `PHP` package that has it built-in

or use `mysqli_connect()` instead of `mysql_connect()`

```
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","runner_db_user","runner_db_password","ntc_race_info");
```